# How can I restore the git history of a fork where the history was deleted?

Tags: git

I have a project with hundreds of commits. It is a fork of another open-source project. At the time the fork was created, the git history was wiped. Now I want to reattach the history.

The original project has thousands of commits, call them: `A <- B <- C <- D`

Meanwhile, our fork has: `E <- F <- G <- H`

The branches **do not share any common ancestors**, but commit `D` and `E` **have exactly the same filesystem**. When `E` was created, the git history was wiped.

How can I reattach them without solving merge conflicts?

Solutions I've tried:

- `git cherry-pick fork/initial..fork/develop` - I tried cherry-picking changes from the fork onto the original repo, but this resulted in merge conflicts. This solution tries to replay the commits linearly, but with all of the branching and merges that happened, there are merge conflicts all along the way.
- `git rebase -i fork/initial fork/develop~0 --onto new-branch` - Rebasing instead of cherry-picking unfortunately has the same problem as above. It tries to replay the commits in order, leading to merge conflicts. I also tried with `--rebase-merges` to no avail.
- `git merge fork/develop --allow-unrelated-histories` -- This is the closest to what I want. It still resulted in a ton of merge conflicts (for reasons I don't understand?) but I resolved them all at once with `git checkout fork/develop -- .` and `git commit`. The problem with this solution is the "initial commit" of the fork branch is still the oldest commit to touch every file, so I am not getting any of the benefits of consolidating these branches.

All the solutions I’ve encountered so far require me to resolve conflicts. This should not be required, since **I am trying to attach histories at a point where the filesystems are identical.**

I just want to reattach the history to where it came from. Any ideas?

Comment: Rebase E-thru-H onto D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
git rebase --onto D E H
```

That should put F, G and H on top of D.... well, not exactly. Those would be replicas of the original revisions, of course. That is, assuming E..H is a straight line.

## Update

I have created a script that replicates history of branches on top of another revision *without* actually doing any cherry-picking like what rebase does. It creates new revisions on the fly using the information from the original revisions. Merges included, of course.

https://github.com/eantoranz/git/blob/replay/contrib/replay

Use it standalone, so, if you wanted to do something like `git rebase --the-real-deal --onto new-base old-base tip`, you would do: `./replay new-base old-base tip`. From the example given in the question: `./replay D E H`. The single line it prints in stdout is the ID of the equivalent revision for `the tip` of what you asked to replay.

Comment: E..H is not a straight line, so this results in merge conflicts (even though those conflicts are resolved by merge commits in later commits).

Comment: Rebase with `--ours`?

Comment: Ok.... I see that matts comment was about the comment from Alex.

Comment: I don't have much experience with grafts, but perhaps it is one of the scenarios where they are handy?

Comment: How does it go with `--rebase-merges`?

Comment: @matt Using `-X ours` or `-X theirs` both resulted in minor differences from the fork branch, but I was able to resolve those manually. This is good enough for my use case, so thank you!

Comment: Sounds like an upvote is on the way ;-)

Comment: I created a script that you might want to look at. It's like the rebase I said but you won't need to solve any conflicts. It should replicate the new revisions from the original revisions (including the trees) so no conflict will arise. https://github.com/eantoranz/git/blob/replay/contrib/replay Use it "standalone": `./replay D E H`. If you want to keep the committers from the revisions, use `--keep-committer`

Comment: @eftshift0 Does "revision" = "commit"?

Comment: yep, a revision is a commit

Comment: @eftshift0, thank you for your efforts! I ran the script and it succeeded, but after running `git log` and scrolling to the bottom, the oldest commit is still commit `E` from the fork. It did not include the history from the original repo. Note that I also had to remove type assertions from lines 83 and 102 to make the script run, otherwise I was seeing `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. I'm running Python 3.10.4.

Comment: Just to clarify, I understand it produced a new commit and didn't change the working tree. I ran `git log <new-commit>` and scrolled to the bottom. Commit E's hash is unchanged, while its descendants all had new IDs. Git v2.35.1.

Comment: Oh.... I think you are right. Let me see.

Comment: Just pushed a new fixed version. If I didn't add a mapping between the old base to the new base, you would end up working on top of the old base so not really doing anything useful.

Comment: The error you are seeing.... could that be related to tags? Hope it works better now. Let me know (though I would expect the assertions to have to be removed again from the script.... or that you are cloning so you can merge your changes :-))

Comment: It worked!! That is incredible. The new history is absolutely perfect. Thank you so much! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I marked it as the answer. That is really awesome, and I'm sure it will help others later on.

Comment: Glad to know! See you around!

Comment: I gave it a shot to try to see if git community is interested but it's not looking good at the time. :-D https://marc.info/?l=git&m=164986824819974